# How to properly run "top" command through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, top

I have to run **top** command on one computer being on another.
My targeted PC has IP 192.168.0.81

I was trying to do it: **ssh 192.168.0.81 top**

But I got this result: **top: tcgetattr() failed: Invalid argument**

Could anybody help me with this issue?

System info: Linux iRP-C-09 2.4.18-timesys-4.0.642

Top version:  2.0.7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`top` is a full screen interactive console application.  It requires a tty to run.  Try `ssh -t` or `ssh -tt` to force pseudo-tty allocation.

Comment: @AlexWih, then you probably should mark *this* as the correct answer, rather than the off topic one.

Comment: Sure, I did it.

Comment: thank you! that fixed me an issue which kept me busy way too long!

Comment: What are the differences between `ssh -t` and `ssh -tt`?

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to see interactive display, you could let it output only one-snapshot then you no longer need "ssh -t" option:

```
top -n 1 -b
```

Comment: Or, more tersely: `top -bn1`

Answer (score 1):

Little bit off-topic:

If you need more (and better looking) output, you could also try `atop`. You can download it [here](http://atoptool.nl/). Very useful to debug performance issues. It can also log system performance, so you can "rewind and playback" a problem.